# Browse only "UNIX Printer" with avahi-browse

Tags: home-networking, browsing, avahi

I'm running Debian Buster with `avahi-daemon` and `avahi-utils` (for `avahi-browse`) installed. Now I simply want to browse only for UNIX Printer on my home network. If I browse for all services I find my printer:

```
~$ avahi-browse -at
+   ens1 IPv4 printer living room       Internet Printer     local
+   ens1 IPv4 printer living room       PDL Printer          local
+   ens1 IPv4 printer living room       UNIX Printer         local
+   ens1 IPv4 printer living room       _scanner._tcp        local
+   ens1 IPv4 printer living room       Web Site             local
+   ens1 IPv4 printer living room       _privet._tcp         local
```

Now I'm browsing for a service type:

```
~$ avahi-browse -t _scanner._tcp
+   ens1 IPv4 printer living room       _scanner._tcp        local
```

Works, but having problems with `UNIX Printer` as shown as service type:

```
~$ avahi-browse -t UNIX Printer
Too many arguments
~$ avahi-browse -t "UNIX Printer"
avahi_service_browser_new() failed: Invalid service type
~$ avahi-browse -t 'UNIX Printer'
avahi_service_browser_new() failed: Invalid service type
~$ avahi-browse -t UNIX\ Printer
avahi_service_browser_new() failed: Invalid service type
```

`UNIX Printer` is contained in the service type database:

```
~$ avahi-browse -b | grep "UNIX Printer"
UNIX Printer
```

Why I cannot browse for a single service using its friendly name contained in the service type database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the program wasn't written to reverse-lookup the friendly names in this situation<sup>1</sup>. (And maybe it was deliberate as the friendly names aren't guaranteed to be stable nor unique? Not to mention Avahi-specific.)

You should find out the raw service name using `-k, --no-db-lookup` and then use that:

```
avahi-browse _printer._tcp
```

---

<sup>1</sup> I went and checked the source code and it literally doesn't even have a reverse lookup function defined. There is only stdb_lookup() for querying the friendly name based on actual name.

Comment: The `-k` option was the solution to my problem. Thanks :-)